# How to use NumberExpr in graphite query in bosun

Tags: graphite, bosun

I use macro to define core calculations. And I'd like to have as less params to define for the macro as possible. So, I have a macro that base it's calculations on the variable `$period`. Then I try to use a variable that related to `period` in the graphite query, but I receive an error.

Simplified code:

```
# defined outside a macro
$period_min = 5

#macro, skipping irrelevant variables
$control_period_min = $period_min * 3

$periods = graphiteBand( $expr, "${control_period_min}m", "1h", "tag", 1 )
```

Produces:

> graphiteBand: time: unknown unit  *  in duration 5 * 3m

I wonder, is it possible to implement the same logic different way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Variables are just string replacement. Since you have put it in quotes, you are making a string that would be literally "5 * 3".

What you can do is use the `tod()` [function](http://bosun.org/expressions.html#todscalar-string):

```
# defined outside a macro
$period_min = 5

#macro, skipping irrelevant variables
$control_period_min = $period_min * 3

avg(q("avg:rate:os.cpu{host=*bosun*}", tod($control_period_min), ""))
```

Comment: I was looking for something like 'tod' but couldn't find anything. Thank you a lot for helping!

Comment: By the way, for the future readers: be aware that tod accepts seconds, not minutes! So, proper value for my example will be `$control_period_sec = $period_min * 3 * 60`

Comment: @Microfed also see the `d()` func where you can return the number of s a second from the string. They can work together: i.e `tod(d("5m") * 5)`